# QGIS distance between centroids from NUTS1 information

Tags: qgis, centroids, distance-matrix

I have calculated the centroids from NUTS1 information. Now for every neighbor centroids, I would like to calculate the distance. I want to connect only the neighbor's Centroids regarding the NUTS1. I tried the formula join attributes by nearest but as the title suggests joins the nearest and not the neighbors.

Here is a screenshot of the problem

[image]

Any suggestions?

Furthermore, after tries, I manage to solve the problem. First I created a distance matrix with k nearest equal to 7. Then I duplicate the distance matrix and by using "Join by lines" I connected all the relevant centroids. At this point, I start manually deleting the lines that were not correct according to the neighbor's idea. After that, I checked the attribute table (in order to save in a csv) but there were multiple duplicates for the same connected line. Perhaps the command Join by lines caused the duplicates problem. I export it in excel. Where I could erase easily all the duplicates with a command.

The map looks like that right now

[image]

Comment: I susgest you provide a screenshot indicating, how nearest and neighbours differ.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment and suggestions https://prnt.sc/10gye5d here is a screenshot. So the main problem is that I want to connect every centroid with the neighbor one. I

Comment: By "neighbours" do you mean two regions that share a land border?

Comment: @Spacedman yes :)

Comment: Please add the new information (duplicates etc) in your post, by [editing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/389427/edit) it, instead of sending links in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Join Attributes By Location" with the "touches" predicate:

[image]

This will return a polygon layer with lots of polygons in it. Here's a chunk of the attribute table:

[image]

showing (look at the `fid` and `fid_2` columns) region 1 neighbours regions 2 and 3, and region 10 neighbours regions 9, 22, and 20. So the geometry for region 1 is repeated twice, and the geometry for region 10 is repeated 3 times. Depending on what you want to do with the adjacency you could drop the geometry and have this is a non-geometric table and then join it to you polygons via QGIS 'Join' on the `fid`.

The X and Y attributes here were the start of an attempt to draw the connecting lines for this neighbourhood network, but I've not done that yet.

Comment: thank you @spacedman for your suggestion.

Comment: I manage to create my distance table, the problem is that I have too many duplicates do you know how can I eliminate duplicates. I am attaching a screenshot.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/10h55bk

Comment: Have you done some more processing to get that attribute table - looks like the output from "hub lines", in which case how did you make that and were there duplicates in the "join attributes by location" step - which you've not shown us. This might be another question.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comments. Do you have a suggestion how can I clean the duplicated from this attribute table. https://prnt.sc/10h6c06

Comment: If you want to know how to remove features by duplicated attribute, first search for answers on the web and then if you can't find out how you should *create a new question* here and not add a comment. We can't do full answers in comments and we like to do one answer to one question in each post here.

Comment: I can totally understand. It was more like a follow-up :) thank you again for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Virtual Layer that will query the polygon layer twice and compute the distance. It is actually simpler to compute the centroids on the fly

go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Feel free to add more fields from both layers.

```sql
SELECT a.id, b.id, st_distance(st_centroid(a.geometry),st_centroid(b.geometry)) dist
FROM myPolygonLayer a
  JOIN myPolygonLayer b ON ST_INTERSECTS(a.geometry,b.geometry)
WHERE a.id <> b.id
```

The line `WHERE a.id <> b.id` will returns the same distance twice (from A to B, and from B to A). If you want a single distance, change it to `WHERE a.id > b.id 1`

If you do need/want to use the already computed centroid layer, you would need to add two more joins to the query. You can add any field from `p1` (the source polygon), `c1` (the centroid from the source polygon), `p2` (the neighbor polygon) and `c2`(the centroid from the neighbor polygon)

```sql
SELECT p1.id, p2.id, st_distance(c1.geometry,c2.geometry) dist
FROM myPolygonLayer p1
 JOIN myPointLayer c1 ON ST_INTERSECTS(p1.geometry,c1.geometry)
 JOIN myPolygonLayer p2 ON ST_INTERSECTS(p1.geometry,p2.geometry)
 JOIN myPointLayer c2 ON ST_INTERSECTS(p2.geometry,c2.geometry)
WHERE c1.id <> c2.id
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. Perhaps do you know how to clean the duplicates from the following attribute table https://prnt.sc/10h6c06 ?

Comment: duplicates here are likely caused by duplicates in your input(s). Pick one ID and check if you have multiple polygons/points for it